# Python Mayavi: How can I hide the scene window?

Tags: python, mayavi

When using mayavi in a python script, how can I hide the scene window?

I would like to create a jpeg and have the output directly to a jpeg, and not have a separate scene window appear when I run the mayavi script.

Example:

```
mlab.figure(bgcolor=(0,0,0),size=(1200,1200))
s = mlab.points3d(x,y,z)
mlab.savefig('output.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, it looks like it is easy:

```
mlab.options.offscreen = True
```